# What is correct way to calibrate battery?

Tags: battery, calibration

I've watched videos and referred some random sites. 
But I'm not sure if these steps are correct.

I used battery calibration app but that doesn't help.

I'm using Asus Zenfone Max Pro M2. 
Running on stable pie.

So how to calibrate battery accurately?

Comment: May I ask you to elaborate on what you imagine "calibrating" your phone battery means.

Comment: Even customer care told me to calibrate that about battery cycle. 0 to 100 and 100 to 0  that's battery cycle.

Comment: Okay; then what do you hope to accomplish?  _"I used battery calibration app but that doesn't help."_  Help with what?

Comment: With battery calibration.

Comment: I get that - let me be a little more clear.  "Battery calibration" is an overloaded phrase and most often does not mean anything.  The electrochemistry variability in lithium-ion batteries means you can't definitively say the battery is 100% charged to capacity when your phone reports the percentage as such.  So, you "calibrate" your battery with an app... again, meaningless... then what?  What's your _goal_ by this mythical calibration?

Comment: So is it myth? I don't know that if it is myth.

Comment: And they also have mentioned that batterystat.bin file will be updated after calibration and then battery draining issue will be fixed.

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-engineer-debunks-myth-wiping-battery-stats-does-not-improve-battery-life/

Comment: Thank you. So I should get my phone checked than wasting time to this myth. Thanks again.